# $(selector).find().live() returning the parent from a multiple selector

Tags: jquery

I'm having some trouble with `.find()` on a `.live()` returning the wrong element.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="div1">
    <input type="text" id="txt1" />
</div>
```

**Javascript (jQuery):**

```
$('#div1,#div2').find('input').live('keypress',function() {
   console.log(this);
});
```

I expect

```
<input id="txt1" type="text">
```

to be returned, but instead I'm getting back

```
<div id="div1">
```

Any thoughts on why I would be getting the parent container `div` of the `input` instead of the `input` itself?

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/6rxCu/5/)

---

**Addendum:**

I'm not really looking for alternate code that works (I could easily split this into two `.live()` calls), I'm just trying to find out why this doesn't work.

Yes, I realize that #div2 does not exist.

Yes, I realize that the documentation for .live() says to [only attach .live() to the root selector](http://api.jquery.com/live/#caveats).  However, $(selector).find().live() [works in simpler situations](http://jsfiddle.net/6rxCu/4/).

Comment: What happens if you create a `#div2` and add it into the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the code:

```
console.log($("#div1, #div2").find("input").selector);
```

You will see

```
#div1, #div2 input
```

That is why you are seeing the output of a div when you log 'this'.  As to why this is happening, I am not sure. I would think if you use $("...").find, the find parameter would be applied to all arguments in the initial selector.

To solve this I would just write the selector as:

```
$("#div1 input, #div2 input").live('keypress',function() {
    console.log(this);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the thorough input and a good solution.  It's still killing me why the `div` is being returned...

Answer (score 1):

I forked your fiddle and added a `#div2` into the HTML. You can see it here: http://jsfiddle.net/w9U34/ Interestingly enough, if you do a keypress on the second `input` it'll return the input, but if you do it in the first it returns a `div`.

Comment: Ha, that is really interesting

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
$('#div1 input, #div2 input').live('keypress',function() {
    console.log(this);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for a good suggestion for the solution, but I'm dying to know why it's returning the `div` in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `.delegate()` in all situations where you think `.live()` would be beneficial.

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/JAAulde/6rxCu/12/

It is more efficient to do so, anyway, because `.live()` is just a special alias to `.delegate()` now.