# jQuery: Nested Multiple Selector unexpected behaviour

Tags: jquery

Why does this code:

```
var jQueryString="div.data > div.item > div.quantity,div.article,div.price > :input";  
$(jQueryString).live("click", function(event) { alert(this); });
```

output `[object HTMLDivElement]` instead of `[object HTMLInputElement]`?

[JSFiddle example here](http://jsfiddle.net/FDNMD/10).

I know this is a similar question to [selector-find-live-returning-the-parent-from-a-multiple-selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6933858/selector-find-live-returning-the-parent-from-a-multiple-selector), but I want a better solution (**to get the HTML element I want modifying only the jQueryString**).

---

**updating**

this was a code sample for didactic understanding, i can't accept a solution like "define a jquery search string by each INPUT", cuz in the real code there are a lof of INPUTS.

the answer of @Sotiris is too close to be perfect.

---

**updating**

the perfect solution is :: [jQuery, Real :not operator equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7747785/jquery-real-not-operator-equivalent)
= thanks to all :P =

Comment: `$(this) dot method_you_want_to_call()` e.g., `$(this).val()`

Comment: you are directly echoing `this` and you are getting a valid output since the 'browser' doesn't know what exactly to display for a 'complex object' (as opposed to simple variable)

Comment: @Nupul, Hi!, this is not what i am looking for, read again :P

Comment: Did! Sorry my bad: Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/FDNMD/1/  What I don't get is the need for such specific parent based selector string. Changing it to `div.data input` gives you what you want

Comment: @Nupul, the point is, jQuery is returning the DIV.QUANTITY, not the INPUT element.

Comment: As I said...and as the others have said below you could just get rid of the comma separated list of divs or simplify the parent/child relationship in your selectors. Can you always guarantee that the relation will always be maintained if any changes are made to the site?

Comment: check the answer of @Sotiris :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because in your selector you don't select three inputs but two divs and one input.

`div.data > div.item > div.quantity`  select a `div`

`div.article` select the `div.article`

the following select the input

```
div.price > :input
```

In the following demo you can see that all of them alert `[object HTMLInputElement]` using `"div.data > div.item > div.quantity > :input,div.article > :input,div.price > :input"`

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/FDNMD/7/

Comment: this was iam looking for, the code sample works perfectly, but currently iam trying to understand how this works :B

Comment: can you update your fiddle code??, setting " alert( this.id ); " to help to understand to others what i am trying to say. thanks!

Comment: waiting for that updating, once i make this the accepted solution.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the following line, because commas don't nest as you're expecting:

```
var jQueryString =  "#quantity, #article, #price";
```

**See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FDNMD/4/**

Your CSS selector is interpreted in this way:

```
div.data > div.item > div.quantity, /* Select DIV with class quantity*/
div.article, /* Select div with class article */
div.price > :input /* Select input element which is a child of div.price */
```

IDs should only occur once. Since you've already defined an `ID` attribute for these elements, you can use the ID selectors, instead of nested selectors.

#### Update

Commas separate whole selectors. Consider the following, real-life language:

> A smart choice consists of a, b, c, d, e

In CSS, you cannot construct "sentences" like that. Instead, you have to specify the whole selector again:

> A smart choice consists of a,
> A smart choice consists of b,
> ...etc.

CSS:

```
root a, b, c {} /*You did probably not want this*/

/*Desired selector set: */
root a, root b, root c {}
/* More readable: */
root a,
root b,
root c {}
```

**[This page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS_Reference#Basic_Selectors)** may also interest you (not about commas, but CSS selectors in general):

Comment: To verify this: make this change in your fiddle: `alert($(this).val())` and you'll see that when you click price the value actually exists!!! Blank (empty text) for div.quantity and  div.article!!!

Comment: +100 if I could for a beautiful explanation of the interpretation!

Comment: @Nupul Previously, the dialog showed `DIV`, rather than `INPUT`. The transition from `HTMLDivElement` to `HTMLInputElement` should satisfy the OP.

Comment: good point, but this was a code sample, the real code is a really nested input with an ID generated dinamically, so i can't select by ID (:

Comment: @iim.hlk See my updated answer. Now, do you understand how (comma-separated) selectors work?

Comment: wow!, you are a good kid!, is real the point of "In CSS, you cannot construct "sentences" like that ", but obviously currently there are a LOT of things CSS can't do and jQuery yes. Check the answer of @Sotiris, that was iam looking for :)

Comment: @iim.hlk The comma-behavior in JQuery is the same as in CSS. Sortiris' answer is in the same format as my answer: `root a, root b, root c` instead of `root a,b,c`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

http://jsfiddle.net/FDNMD/6/

Multiple div selectors breaks it, for some reason

Comment: thats a good solution but, there is a way to make this USING the jquery OR operator?, i dont want set one line by each input ( cuz this was a code sample, the real code is a really nested input )

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the multipe div elements (div.article, div.price), it works. E.g.,

```
var jQueryString="div.data > div.item > div.quantity > :input";
$(jQueryString).live("click", function(event) { alert(this); });
```

This is a problem with precedence of operators. The commas in the list of divs takes a different precedence than what you expect.

To further prove my point, I looked at your example, and I noticed that on the third button it does work properly. jQuery is interpreting your expression as 3 sub-expressions:

- div.data > div.item > div.quantity
- div.article
- div.price > :input

Comment: good try!, i dont want set one line by each input ( cuz this was a code sample, the real code is a really nested input,,, with a lot of INPUTS )