# jQuery, REAL :not operator equivalent?

Tags: jquery

this code line select all the children inputs inside any div who his class name is not "id" and "quantity" ::

```
$("div.item > div:not(.id,.quantity) > :input").live("keydown",function(event) {});
```

**what is the code line to do the opposite?**, something like ::

```
$("div.item > div:filter(.id,.quantity) > :input").live("keydown",function(event) {});
```

( of course `:filter` is not a valid jQuery selector )

Comment: There is a [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/), though.

Comment: i can't use .filter() cuz that preclude the use of .live() event handler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if I would recommend this, but you can use `:not` twice:

```
$("div.item > div:not(:not(.id,.quantity)) > :input")
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6aW2B/

A better way is to create your own `:is` selector

```
$.expr[':'].is = function(elem, index, match){
    return $(elem).is(match[3]);
};

$("div.item > div:is(.id,.quantity) > :input")
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8Uny2/

Comment: WOW!, i did not know that use of the :not operator, hey that JUST WORK AMAZING! ( so smart, so simple ), your Parents were telling the truth when say "You Are Wonderful!!" :B

Comment: @iim.hlk Please do not attempt to edit other people's answers in such a radical fashion. You can note in a comment which aspects were most useful to you.

Answer (score 3):

I presume you are thinking of an "or" concept. Unfortunately, this doesn't really exist in jQuery/CSS selection. You need to do an "or" for the whole selection:

```
$('div.item > div.id > :input, div.item > div.quantity > :input')
```

If you are not using `live`, the easiest way to do this is with DOM traversal:

```
$('div.item').children('div.id, div.quantity').children(':input')
```

Since you are using `live`, the first example is probably the simplest technique.

Comment: thats really the UNIQUE solution?, i need define each line per children div?, my real code is something like "form#dinamic > div.articleListContainer > div.area2 > div.data > div.itemModifing > DIV.ID > :input", in other way "too long".

Comment: @iim.hlk Are all those classes *really* necessary? Could you not do, say `form#dinamic div.id > :input`?